# find nearest element with jquery from a 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with multiple instances of a div with `class="abstract"` and I am using '*each*' to iterate through and the current `div` found is stored in '*this*'.

Given '*this*' contains the div and all its contents how can I traverse up 2 levels of divs to set the color of a div?

e.g.

```
$(this).closest('div').find('heading').css("background-color", "green"); //not working
```

The actual div structure relative to the iterated div (abstract) is:

```
<div class=heading>
<div class=body>
<div class=abstract>
```

Comment: Use $(this).closest('div.heading').css("background-color", "green");

Comment: It's probably best not to tie your logic to your DOM structure. Instead, tie to your class structure, as @j08691 suggests.

Comment: i want to rely on class structure but for some reason only the .parent method is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`$(this).parent().parent().find('.heading').css("background-color", "green");`

Comment: If he's iterating over the .abstract elements then this would fail

Comment: [Why "Try" or "Try this:" makes for a bad answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552).

Comment: nice! if you need something else just tell us.

Answer (score 0):

If div.abstract is a grandchild of div.heading and you iterate over the div.abstract elements, you would use:

```
$(this).closest('.heading').css("background-color", "green");
```

Comment: Then you'll need to post a [mcve] as your code is incomplete. My answer would work based on the little information you provided.

Comment: I will but for the moment I will accept the answer that works -- i am curious as to why it doesn't work though

Comment: Don't accept an answer unless it solves your problem *and* you understand why. You **need** to post a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: i understand why the accepted answer works - i dont understand why the other solution does not work

Comment: For the third, and last, time. Please post a [mcve]